# AngularJS Call WebMethod an return a JSON string

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json, webmethod

i have implemented a simple Webmethod in c# that returns a JSON string, in this way:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        string retStr = "Hello World";
        string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retStr);
        return jsonStr;
    }
```

This method is called by an angularjs function:

```
angular.module('IndexApp', [])
.controller('IndexController', function ($scope, $element, $http) {
    $scope.retData = {};
    $scope.retData.getResult = function (item, event) {
        $http.get('/WebMethods/HTTP_GET.asmx/HelloWorld', { data: {} })
            .then(function (data ̶,̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶,̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶,̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶ ) {
                $scope.retData.result = data.data.d;
            }),
            function errorCallback(response) { }
    }
}).config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";  

});
```

The problem is that on client side functions, in data.data variable, i retrive an XML instead of a json string.
How can i do to let return a JSON instead of XML?
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: try this => `[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string HelloWorld() {}`

Comment: The `.then` method exposes a `response` object, not `(data, status, headers, config)`.

Comment: Hello er-shoaib, added but still not working...

Comment: @pasluc74669, did u try the answers in link given in above comment?

Comment: yes, it is the same issue, but it uses Jquery, and I use angularjs instead...

Comment: Check item one in the checklist "Did you specify type: "POST" in the ajax request?". Your code erroneously uses a "GET" request, i.e. `$http.get`.